# Automatic slice of polygon

Tags: polygon, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I have a data source, that sometimes returns geometries which are not properly cleaned e.g.
[image]

the pink polygon is only 0.02 cm wide and is always on the edge of the whole geometry which consists of the brown polygon and the yellow one.

Is there a programmatic way I could prolong the yellow/brown border and with that line slice the pink one and merge the resulting two pink polygons to their neighbor?

So far I had to do this manually in QGIS using the vertex tool, but I would like to do this automatically using JTS or Geotools, as it is a bit time consuming.